# Text Colour of OK & Cancel button in Date picker dialogue is not changing and remains white only

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, datepicker, themes

I want to change the colour of OK and Cancel text colour in date picker dialogue to black , but it remains white only. I used

```
 <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
```

in the date picker style , to change the colour of the OK text but it is not working !! What's the problem and how to change its colour ?

[image: OK text (in white colour) without button background color]
[image: OK text (in white colour) with button background color]

// themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.DOBCalc" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/font9</item>
</style>

<style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/txtBg</item>
    <!--selected Item color-->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/txtBg</item>
    <!-- arrow bordercolor(<>)-->
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Highlight item color-->
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/bgColor</item>
    <!--Calender Background color -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Ok Cancel Color-->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

    <!-- Week TextColor-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/txtBg</item>
    <!-- Calender Number color arrow color (< >) -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <!--day , month-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ffffff</item>
    <!-- year-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#ffffff</item>

</style>
```

// MainActivity.kt file

```
    package com.nandini.android.dobcalc

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private var dateTv : TextView?=null
    private var minTv : TextView?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnDatePicker : Button = findViewById(R.id.btnDatePicker)
        dateTv=findViewById(R.id.date_tv)
        minTv=findViewById(R.id.min_tv)

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener {
         datePicker()
        }

    }

    private fun datePicker ()
    {
        val myCalender = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = myCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = myCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = myCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this,R.style.datepicker,
            { _, selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay ->
                Toast.makeText(this,"Year was $selectedYear , ${selectedMonth+1}'s $selectedDay day.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val selectedDate="$selectedDay/${selectedMonth+1}/$selectedYear"
                dateTv?.text = selectedDate
                val sdf= SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH)
                val theDate=sdf.parse(selectedDate)

                theDate?.let {

                    val selectedDateInMin=theDate.time / 60000
                    val currentDate=sdf.parse(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))

                    currentDate?.let {

                        val currentDateInMin=currentDate.time/60000
                        val differenceInMin = currentDateInMin-selectedDateInMin
                        minTv?.text=differenceInMin.toString()
                    }

                } },year,month,day)
            dpd.datePicker.maxDate=System.currentTimeMillis()-86400000
            dpd.show()


    }
}
```

// activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate your"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txtColor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/txtBg"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txtColor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Minutes"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txtColor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#D9EADD"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Select Date"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/txtBg"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00.00.00"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/txtColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Minutes"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#98B0A8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txtColor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Minutes"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#98B0A8" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#1d302b</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#0f1815</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="bgColor">#49796B</color>
    <color name="txtColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="txtBg">#2c4940</color>
    <color name="buttonBg">#D9EADD</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code :-

```
dpd.show()
dpd.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

xml attributes:

```
 colorOnPrimary -> For the text color of OK/CANCEL buttons
```

You must add this attribute to the dialog style.